# How to properly configure a 2 node glusterfs system?

Tags: linux, centos7, glusterfs

I am trying to make a 2 node linux servers with high available apache using glusterfs 3.7.6 for data replication and pacemaker+corosync as resource manager. However i'm seeing a problem with gluster in the specific scenario when both nodes get shutdown and one of them comes online first. Even though there's a brick on that node and gluster service is running, there's no brick process.

```
[root@node1 ~]# gluster volume status data 
Status of volume: data
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick node1:/gluster_data                   N/A       N/A        N       N/A  
NFS Server on localhost                     N/A       N/A        N       N/A  
NFS Server on localhost                     N/A       N/A        N       N/A  

Task Status of Volume data
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active volume tasks
```

And when I start the other node, everything seems to work and I can mount the volume.

```
[root@node1 ~]# gluster volume status data
Status of volume: data
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick node1:/gluster_data                  49152      0          Y       2674 
Brick node2:/gluster_data                  49152      0          Y       3086 
NFS Server on localhost                     N/A       N/A        N       N/A  
Self-heal Daemon on localhost               N/A       N/A        Y       2796 
NFS Server on node2                         N/A       N/A        N       N/A  
Self-heal Daemon on node2                   N/A       N/A        Y       3085 

Task Status of Volume data
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active volume tasks
```

And at this point if I shut down node2, node1 brick process remains active so atleast I can mount and use it.

```
[root@node1 ~]# gluster volume status data

Status of volume: data
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick node1:/gluster_data                   49152     0          Y       2674 
NFS Server on localhost                     N/A       N/A        N       N/A  
Self-heal Daemon on localhost               N/A       N/A        Y       2796 

Task Status of Volume data
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active volume tasks
```

So my observation is that for the gluster volume to work, both nodes need to be online atleast for a moment so the bricks can start and then if one node goes down, it won't affect the volume operation. So how can I make it work when one of the nodes come online from a total blackout ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem any cluster-node has when coming up from a full stop is:

> Do I have the latest state, or not? I don't want to claim `latest` if I'm behind the other down nodes.

This is why clustering very often includes some kind of quorum mechanism, so existing nodes can vote on state and converge on a consensus. Two node clusters can't use this mechanism, since there will never be a 'majority' partition. In the 3.7 release, Gluster gained a quorum feature.

http://gluster.readthedocs.org/en/release-3.7.0beta1/Features/server-quorum/

In that document, they state that 2-node clusters can't use it for the very reason I described above.

In your case, you may want to consider creating some management-only nodes in your Gluster setup. These would be peers that are `probed` into the cluster, but don't host any storage. Their entire reason to exist would be to maintain cluster-state. These can exist in different racks, datacenters, power phases, to try and ensure they are in a different fault-domain than the storage bricks. This will increase the number of members in a cluster, and will improve your chances of having a majority partition if one of the storage-bricks comes up without the other one.

Unfortuonately, the behavior you're seeing is *working as designed* and can't be changed without adding more servers into the cluster.

Comment: Thanks a million for the excellent explanation !! This is the best kind of answer with both explanation of the underlying reason and suggestion on how to avoid it. Thanks a lot again.